# Find all calls to method in java classes

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, reference

I've a huge project with many classes. I've a very specific class; let's name it `SuperFoo`. I need to find all calls to the method `equals()` with argument of type `Superfoo`. Hope it's clear.

So, one more time... in thousands of java files (or bytecode?) I'd like to find all calls to the method `java.lang.Object.equals(Object arg)` but the argument to this call must be of type `SuperFoo`. For example:

```
public void doItWith(SuperFoo foo) {
    if (otherFoo.equals(foo)){
         // do something
    }
...
}
```

I checked out Browse-by-query, analyzing bytecode and just Java Search in Eclipse and in my opinion none of this works.

Comment: http://depfind.sourceforge.net/Manual.html may help.

Comment: Quick and dirty answer; change the method signature and watch your IDE display all the errors.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc that wont work. the compiler will call Object.equals instead

Answer (score 1):

A programmatic approach would be to use [Aspect Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) (i.e. [AspectJ](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/)). You would define a pointcut to capture the method call of interest

```
pointcut equals(Superfoo o) = call(boolean *.equals(Object)) && args(o);
```

and then use advice to select each occurrence and query the joinpoint object to get the static information i.e. where it appears in your code.

```
before(Superfoo o) : equals(o) {
  System.out.println("An occurence at "+thisJoinPoint.getSourceLocation());
}
```

Comment: With compile-time weaving, is it possible to find out all of the join-points before runtime?

Comment: There's probably a nicer way of doing it - but if you use AspectJ in Eclipse you can ask it for all the places a join-point matches.

Comment: I checked it out and this pointcut matches all calls to 'equals' method (not only with argument of type SuperFoo) :( any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

So, you are trying to find out the references of

```
public boolean equals(Object o)
```

overridden in SuperFoo. If you have access to the source code, this could be done in eclipse. If you go for Call Hierarchy, eclipse returns back all the occurrence of Object's equals() method. So, you need try the following:

Open SuperFoor. Select the equals method. Right Click. References --> Project. In the resulting search window, on the extreme right, click on the triangle.  Select "references to override". That's it. The results returned initially will be filtered and it will **mostly** contain references of equals overridden in SuperFoo.

Hope this helps.