# Finding method references with given parameter type in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a method `myMethod(Object obj)`. I want to find the places where it is called with `myMethod(myObject)`. Finding all references returns calls of the sort `myMethod(anotherObj)`, where myObject and anotherObj are of different types.

Is this possible?

Comment: Not sure if [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996988/find-all-calls-to-method-in-java-classes/16997409#16997409) might be relevant.

Comment: 5000 looked way too even

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a no-op method that takes YourObject, then all places where it is called with an explicit YourObject would re-route to that method and you could find them with **Search > References > Workspace**.  Afterward you could delete the new method.

```
public void myMethod(Object obj) {
    // yadda yadda
}

public void myMethod(YourObject obj) {
    // Nothing special here, it's only to support the search
}
```

Items that happen at runtime to be of type YourObject (but are declared as some superclass, like Object) won't be detected in this way.

Comment: That's so ninja. Thank you

Comment: Ahh, actually, it's in code for which I only have the JAR and not the source.

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression may help: `myMethod\(YourObject\s+\w+\)`